# Must I use HTTP/2.0 to send Apple Push Notifications? May I use libcurl?

Tags: apple-push-notifications, libcurl, backwards-compatibility, http2

This question, as you may have inferred from the title, is really two questions in one.

**First Question: *Must I use HTTP/2.0 to send Apple Push Notifications?***

On the [APNs Provider API documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CommunicatingwithAPNs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH11-SW1) provided by Apple, the opening paragraphs specify:

> The provider API is based on the HTTP/2 network protocol.

There are several other references to HTTP/2.0 throughout the documentation. However I don't see (which is not to say it's not there) anything specifying that HTTP/2.0 ***must*** be used. Does this mean that I am allowed to use any HTTP version? Or am I in fact constrained to HTTP/2.0?

I am very familiar with HTTP/1.1 but I know almost nothing about HTTP/2.0, thus if I am able to use my old familiar protocol I would prefer that.

**Second Question (predicated on first question): *May I use libcurl with APNs?***

This question is only relevant given an affirmative answer to the first question. If it's not true that I must use HTTP/2.0 with APNs then I already know that I can use libcurl.

I will be sending many APNs from an already busy server and I would prefer to do it natively - therefore I plan to use libcurl if possible. However I understand that libcurl is somewhat limited when it comes to HTTP/2.0.

The main problem is that when libcurl makes an HTTP/2.0 connection, it actually starts with an HTTP/1.1 request that includes an `upgrade` header, and then waits for a `101 Switching Protocols` status line. Is this behavior supported with APNs? Or must I try to use something like [nghttp2](https://nghttp2.org/)?

I have found that nghttp2 is somewhat complex and *very* poorly documented at the moment. I'm worried that if I can't use libcurl I might end up having to implement HTTP/2.0 on my own using sockets (which would be THE WORST).

**Any help is appreciated for either question! Thank you, everybody!**

Comment: curl the command line is good for this scenario with HTTP/2. Just use the --http2 option and and https:// url . So, there must be a way in which you can make libcurl behave also....

Comment: HTTP/2 done over a normal HTTP:// URL where we don't know which version it speaks is typically done with Upgrade: HTTPS:// is done differently. libcurl _will_ eventually get prior-knowledge HTTP2 support too and you're welcome to help us implement it.

Comment: @DanielStenberg I would actually be interested in helping. That sounds fun. How could I get involved?

Comment: you'd be most welcome! Join the curl-library mailing list, state what you want to help out with and we'll guide you from there (and discuss solutions). Also read http://curl.haxx.se/dev/contribute.html or perhaps this chapter in my coming book: http://ec.haxx.se/sourcecode-contributing.html

Comment: "The Apple Push Notification service (APNs) will no longer support the legacy binary protocol as of November 2020." https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=11042019a

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OK after a good deal of time I finally found the answer. **Yes, HTTP/2 is *required* to use APNS**.

It comes down to a single line in [the APNS docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CommunicatingwithAPNs.html) that says

> APNs requires the use of HPACK (header compression for HTTP/2), which prevents repeated header keys and values.

which would imply that HTTP/2 is a required part of the protocol.

Comment: quick check with the sandbox apn server: it delivers push notifications with HTTP/1.1 ... I haven't tested the production one yet.

Answer (score 4):

As it stands right now, Apple is still supporting its legacy v2 (binary) API, which works over HTTPS, so HTTP/2 is only required if you want to use the latest API.

The legacy API is documented in an appendix, but honestly, compared to the HTTP/2 API, it is so horrible that I could not recommend using it.

I can say for sure that the legacy API is supported because I have production code that is using it right now (this is also why I can say the API is horrible, and I am busy migrating it to HTTP/2).

Comment: Do you migrate to the new HTTP/2 API?
If yes then please let me ask some questions about that.
I am also doing the same

Comment: The legacy system doesn't work over HTTPS. It's not HTTP at all. It's a TLS encrypted binary protocol that does not adhere to any standard.

Comment: The binary API will cease functioning March 31, 2021.

Answer (score 4):

A sample script using curl to send http2 push message. Given that you have the authentication key from dev site and your version of curl is compiled with http2 support. The `p8 file` should be in the same folder of the script say `apns.sh` file. Run>`bash apns.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

deviceToken=96951ABACECA47F34C2F93D8E58591054E6F2B42691B4EADA6935C19A107A524

authKey="./AuthKey_SLDFJSDLB.p8"
authKeyId=SLDFJSDLB
teamId=ABCDET
bundleId=com.mycompany.myapp
endpoint=https://api.development.push.apple.com
apns_collapse_id="score_update"

read -r -d '' payload <<-'EOF'
{
   "aps": {
      "badge": 2,
      "category": "mycategory",
      "alert": {
         "title": "my title",
         "subtitle": "my subtitle",
         "body": "my body text message 103"
      }
   },
   "custom": {
      "mykey": "myvalue"
   }
}
EOF

# --------------------------------------------------------------------------

base64() {
   openssl base64 -e -A | tr -- '+/' '-_' | tr -d =
}

sign() {
   printf "$1"| openssl dgst -binary -sha256 -sign "$authKey" | base64
}

time=$(date +%s)
header=$(printf '{ "alg": "ES256", "kid": "%s" }' "$authKeyId" | base64)
claims=$(printf '{ "iss": "%s", "iat": %d }' "$teamId" "$time" | base64)
jwt="$header.$claims.$(sign $header.$claims)"

curl --verbose \
   --header "content-type: application/json" \
   --header "authorization: bearer $jwt" \
   --header "apns-topic: $bundleId" \
   --header "apns-collapse-id: $apns_collapse_id"\
   --http2 \
   --data "$payload" \
   $endpoint/3/device/$deviceToken
```

Answer (score 1):

**2021 Update**
YES, the HTTP/2 and JSON method is now required, as the binary protocol is being discontinued as of March 31, 2021.

https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=c88acm2b

> To give you additional time to prepare, the deadline to upgrade to the
> APNs provider API has been extended to March 31, 2021. APNs will no
> longer support the legacy binary protocol after this date.