# Apple Push Notification service SSL (Sandbox & Production) - Production not received notification?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, http2, javapns

Apple has provided now this certificate: 
Apple Push Notification service SSL (Sandbox & Production)

To be used in both development and production,
The new APNS now supports HTTP2.

I'm using this Java library to send notifications:
https://github.com/notnoop/java-apns

The problem is that I receive notifications in the development mode, But I can't receive any in the production mode.

Is the reason for that, Is that java-apns library does not support HTTP2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple has deprecated the old HTTP and now is using HTTP2 protocol.

Please check this :[answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35759770/4004429)

[One Signal](https://onesignal.com/) has updated it's library for this new change.